# Prominent on-screen reminder

Tags: ubuntu, reminders

Every now and then I miss the daily team standup just because I simply forget it if I think over a problem.

Is there a software for Linux desktop (I use Xubuntu) which allows for a prominent on-screen popup or similar to get reminded of an event?

Reminder for a daily standup, means I want to configure it to pop up once daily.

Comment: Please add all of your requirements into the body of your question, thanks :-)

Comment: Should it integrate with a calendar you already use (say, via CalDav, or locally in Evolution) – or shall/can it be a stand-alone solution? Also, though Linux often implies OpenSource: must it be FOSS, or would commercial solutions be acceptable (if there are any) and up to what price?